# SpringBoot + method based hierarchical roles security: ServletContext is required

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I added **method-based security** and added **role hierarchy**. I keep getting the following exception during build:

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory
>   method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **A ServletContext is
>   required to configure default servlet handling**

I tried a lot of different configuration alternatives and none works...
Here is my basic web security configuration class (I added role hierarchy-related beans as you see):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

(...)

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            (...)
            .expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler())
            (...)
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
public SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
}

@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl r = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    r.setHierarchy(Role.getHierarchy());
    return r;
}

(...)

}
```

Here is the separate config file that I created basing on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661192/spring-boot-spring-security-hierarchical-roles):

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class GlobalMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = (DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) super.createExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

I struggled with this for many hours. The related topics I tried are here:

- [Spring Boot + Spring Security + Hierarchical Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661192/spring-boot-spring-security-hierarchical-roles)
- [Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522622/error-creating-bean-with-name-defaultservlethandlermapping)
- [Error creating bean with name defaultServletHandlerMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823600/error-creating-bean-with-name-defaultservlethandlermapping)

**Every help appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found it.

I played around with the class annotations and came to a simple solution: I removed `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` from GlobalMethodSecurityConfig and moved it to WebSecurityConfiguration, where it was before. So it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { (...) }
```

and this:

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration { (...) }
```

The most interesting part is that the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661192/spring-boot-spring-security-hierarchical-roles) advises what didn't work for me.